# How to take the next value from custom list in excel with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to take the next value from the list I have created before. The custom list is the alphabet 'A, B, C....AA, AB, AC...'. When I apply it from B52:G52 and I write 'C' in B52 and drag the cell to G52 the list is applyed so in C52 = D, D52 = E ....

How can I know what is the next value with formula. If I have 'C' in B52 what is the formula that in C52 should be 'D'.

So far I have a cell P1 contains letter 'B' and cell B52=P1 and I have the formula in C52 =IF(C45; B52 + 1; "") that applyes when cell C45 is not empty(blank).

By now if i write 'C' in P1 it is automaticly copied in B52. When I write something in C45,  cell C52 should become 'D'. But the part 'B52+1' is the wrong one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `B52+1` would be fine if you are dealing with numbers, but as you are using letters you need to use the [CHAR()](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/CHAR-function-bbd249c8-b36e-4a91-8017-1c133f9b837a) and [CODE()](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/CODE-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928) functions, plus just referencing cell `C45` in your logical test without defining the test you want to apply to cell `C45` would not produce any results.  To test if cell `C45` is not empty you need a logical test of `C45<>""`

If you was going to go from A-Z you would need to change the formula in cell `C52` to

`=IF(C45<>"",CHAR(CODE(B52)+1),"")`

The problem for you with this formula is that if you used this formula and went past `Z` the next cell would return a `[` as it uses the [ASCII character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)

As you want to go further and step from `Z` to `AA` you will need a more complex formula using [LEN()](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/LEN-LENB-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb), [LEFT()](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c) and [RIGHT()](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f) functions.

Therefore the formula in cell `C52` needs to be

`=IF(C45<>"",IF(B52="Z","AA",IF(LEN(B52)=1,CHAR(CODE(B52)+1),(IF(RIGHT(B52)="Z",CHAR(CODE(LEFT(B52))+1)&"A",LEFT(B52)&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(B52))+1))))),"")`

This go from `A` to `Z`, step from `Z` to `AA` then will give `AA` to `ZZ`